# Power BI: How to change card value and visibility based on selected slicer value

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

I am trying to find a way to alter the visibility and value of a card visual based on the value selected in the slicer. The slicer values are A and B and this is what currently happens when the A or B is selected:

Slicer value A:

[image]

Slicer value B:

[image]

For the first image (slicer A) I would like these cards to be removed entirely (invisible) when A is selected.

For the second image (slicer B) I would like to change the Value 4 card value to be 13% (fixed value) if A is selected in the slicer.

---

If A is selected:

[image]

If B is selected:

[image]

Comment: Your "currently happens" explanation doesnt make sense to me.  Standard Card visuals only support 1 measure - yours show 2.  They also dont support dynamically changing the measure based on a Slicer.  I'm guessing there is more going on than you describe.  Try stating in terms of Power BI objects.

Comment: I am using two separate cards.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create a meassure like shown below, and use this value to display on the card.

```
Total Open Orders = if(calculate(distinctcount('All Plants'[Plant]);allselected('All Plants'[Plant]))=1;SUM(OpenOrders[Total Value]);"N/A")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref my comments above, I don't understand most of your question.

For the "fixed value" requirement, I would use the DAX SELECTEDVALUE function e.g.

```
Value 4 = IF ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Table[SlicerColumn] , "" ) = "A" , 0.13 , SUM ( Table[Value 4] ) )
```